# How to search for two items in notepad++ at the same time

Tags: notepad++

I have a very huge file with size greater than 30Mb. It contains text like below:

```
"Data1" "Data2" "Data3" "time1" "time2" "time3" "Data4" "Data5" "Data6" "time4" "time5" "time6"
```

and there are many lines like above. So let's say I want to search for `Data2` and `Data4` at the same time, however, the search is only accepting one item at a time.

How can I search for two items at single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) - in the `Find` dialogue, under `Search Mode` select `Regular expression` (and make sure that `. matches newline` is not checked):

```
Data2.*Data4
```

Or, if you don't care about the order:

```
Data2.*Data4|Data4.*Data2
```

Comment: Thanks. I did Data2.*Data4 and it selected the matched line. Lets say if I want to search for another item `Data3`, so can I do `Data2.Data3.*Data4`. ?

Comment: @SAndrew - You can chain as many as you like, `.*` means match everything until the next expression (or the end of the line if nothing is after it), so `Data2.*Data3.*Data4.*Data5` etc.

Answer (score 1):

just select the search mode as regularexpression
and in search text as data2|data4

Comment: This will match `Data2` **or** `Data4`, not `Data2` **and** `Data4`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a job for lookahead:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?=.*\bData2\b)(?=.*\bData4\b).+$`
- Replace with: `$1,$2,$3,$4\n`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

  - OR
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?=           # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
    \b              # word boundary
    Data2           # the string to search
    \b              # word boundary
  )             # end lookahead
  (?=           # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
    \b              # word boundary
    Data4           # the string to search
    \b              # word boundary
  )             # end lookahead
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t08ilM/1)

[Further reading about lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

You can add any number of strings to search:

```
^(?=.*\bData1\b)(?=.*\bData2\b)(?=.*\bData3\b)(?=.*\bData4\b).+$
```

This will match lines that contain `Data1` & `Data2` & `Data3` & `Data4` in any order.